# Sitemap for one website in multiple domains

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

I have 2 domains (A and B). The first one (A) is the website.

In sitemap.xml of "A" domain, I have a sub-sitemap in "B" domain with "A" URLs.

`A/sitemap.xml` :

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>
      https://B/sitemap.xml
    </loc>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

`B/sitemap.xml` :

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>
      https://A/one-page
    </loc>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

I have follow the documentation (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en). So these 2 domains are verified in the Google Search Console but Google does not index the sub-sitemap (in "B" domain with "A" URLs). Other sub-sitemap in "A" domain are OK.

FYI: the sitemap is valid because if I send it manually in the Search Console (on the B domain property), URLs is displayed in Google search results. An for multiple reasons, I can't sent it manually every time.

Do you have an idea ? Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of these two domains?  Do they have different content?  Why would you put URLs from one domain into the other's sitemap?

Comment: In reality, we have more that 2 domains. We have a lot of websites with differents domains (A). These ones includes some pages generated from an external webservice (with Vue.js / SSR). The webservice is on B domain. When we create a sitemap, we ask to webservice to create sitemap (so sitemap are created on B domain).

One solution is to download B sitemap on A server and serve it in static. But I prefer to keep separated services because if I want regenerate B sitemap, I don't want to pass by the A server.

Comment: I think sitemaps aren't allowed to have URLs for other domains in them.  So what you are trying to do won't work.

Comment: I have read the part "Manage sitemaps for multiple sites" in https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en
I thought it was OK for my situation. But after the test, I begin to doubt it. :/

Comment: I have added sitemap B with A url in robots.txt of A domain too: https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#sitemaps_cross_submits